# How to assign print output to a variable?

Tags: python, function, variables

How to assign the output of the `print` function (or any function) to a variable?

To give an example:

```
import eyeD3
tag = eyeD3.Tag()
tag.link("/some/file.mp3")
print tag.getArtist()
```

How do I assign the output of `print tag.getArtist` to a variable?

Answer (score 35):

The `print` statement in Python converts its arguments to strings, and outputs those strings to stdout.  To save the string to a variable instead, only convert it to a string:

```
a = str(tag.getArtist())
```

Comment: That won't work if the value of tag.getArtist() contains non-ascii characters, for example `u'Elys\xe9e'`.  The print statement would display Elysée but str() will throw a UnicodeEncodeError.

Comment: @RCross In Python 2, this is indeed true – Unicode strings will be encoded using `sys.stdout.encoding` when printing them. So you will need to use `u'Elys\xe9e'.encode(sys.stdout.encoding)` to get the equivalent of what `print` is doing. In Python 3 you should rarely see this issue, since `str` in Python 3 is Unicode string type, so `str(u'Elys\xe9e')` will leave the string unchanged.

Comment: OP did not ask how to save a string to another string, but to save the output of a print statement. This answer does not address the question.

Comment: @sh37211 It's debatable what exactly the OP asked, and I agree your interpretation is more likely than mine. However, the main purpose of StackOverflow isn't to solve the OP's problem, but to provide a useful resource for people looking for answers to similar problems. It is apparent that for many people this answer solves their problem, so calling this answer "not useful" (by means of a downvote) seems a bit of a stretch.

Comment: str(ValueError) does not equal the output of print(ValueError), in the former newlines are escaped.

Comment: @run_the_race `str(some_error)` does not output anything at all – it just converts `some_error` to a string using its `__str__()` method. If you enter `str(some_error)` in the interactive interpreter, the inrerpreter will show the representation of the string, i.e. `repr(str(some_error))`. So to get a useful comparison, you either need to compare `print(some_error)` with `print(str(some_error))`, and you will see they are the same. In other words, the output of `print(some_error)` function matches the string returned by `str(some_error)`.

Answer (score 30):

To answer the question more generaly `how to redirect standard output to a variable ?`

do the following :

```
from io import StringIO
import sys

result = StringIO()
sys.stdout = result
result_string = result.getvalue()
```

If you need to do that only in some function do the following :

```
old_stdout = sys.stdout  

# your function containing the previous lines
my_function()

sys.stdout = old_stdout
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use parameter `file` to redirect output of `print` function

```
from io import StringIO

s = StringIO()
print(42, file=s)
result = s.getvalue()
```

Answer (score 9):

probably you need one of  `str`,`repr` or `unicode` functions

```
somevar = str(tag.getArtist())
```

depending which python shell are you using

Answer (score 4):

```
somevar = tag.getArtist()
```

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html

Comment: I believe the OP needs the string representation of the object.

Comment: This. Don't take the question too literally. No need for `str`.

Comment: @eumiro: Do you have evidence that the function doesn't return a string?

Comment: Do you have evidence that it *does* return a string?  Converting to a string won't hurt.  To be honest, I believe your answer is what the OP is looking for anyway :)

Comment: There are actually cases when converting to a string *will* hurt.

Answer (score 1):

This is a standalone example showing how to save the output of a user-written function in Python 3:

```
from io import StringIO
import sys

def print_audio_tagging_result(value):
    print(f"value = {value}")

tag_list = []
for i in range(0,1):
    save_stdout = sys.stdout
    result = StringIO()
    sys.stdout = result
    print_audio_tagging_result(i)
    sys.stdout = save_stdout
    tag_list.append(result.getvalue())
print(tag_list)
```

**Output**

```
['value = 0\n']
```