# Save the content of the print statement in Python

Tags: python, printing

I'm using someone's code in `c++` which is called by `python`. I have *no* way of getting into the source code and modify it. When called with `python`, it prints something, and I want to assign this output to a variable. How can I do that?

```
def print_something(string):
    print(string)

x = print_something('foo')
```

```
print(type(x))
```

```
Out[5]: NoneType
```

Ideally, this code would assign `'foo'` to `x` as a string.

Comment: If you can't touch the code of the method, you can't change its behaviour so you can't ask to get back something that is not returned yet

Comment: One option is to write the output to a [temporary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) file and read it back into a variable

Comment: How do you actually call the C++ code? It doesn't show from the Python code you listed. print() is a built-in function in (recent) Python, but you seem to say that print() calls someone else's code written in C++?

Comment: You could use `StringIO` as suggested in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884517/python-assign-print-output-to-a-variable).

Comment: I call it from the cmd. In turn, it uses dll files and so on. Can't really give you more details unfortunately

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can redirect `sys.stdout` to buffer?

```
import sys
from io import StringIO

stdout_backup = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = string_buffer = StringIO()

# this function prints something and I cannot change it:
def my_function():
    print('Hello World')

my_function()  # <-- call the function, sys.stdout is redirected now

sys.stdout = stdout_backup  # restore old sys.stdout

string_buffer.seek(0)
print('The output was:', string_buffer.read())
```

Prints:

```
The output was: Hello World
```

Comment: Or even an open file handle.